# Python3 cythonize from yocto bitbake recipe problem

Tags: python-3.x, yocto, bitbake, cythonize

Let me say this recipe works just fine on our environment with python 2.7, but on new environment where python3 is not. I have no clue why.

Folder/files structure:

```
zurka-plugin-extensions-EstTV-py3   ---> Folder
    setup.py
    dialog.py
    main.py
    plugin.pyc
    __init__.pyc
    Esttv.png
```

BB recipe:

```
DESCRIPTION = "EstTV"
MAINTAINER = "Est"
PV = "4.0"
PR = "r0"

require conf/license/license-gplv2.inc

DEPENDS = "python3 python3-cython python3-cython-native"
RDEPENDS:${PN} = " python3-requests python3-multiprocessing python3-image python3-json ffmpeg "
RRECOMMENDS:${PN} = " python3-pillow nesto-plugin-systemplugins-kauz "

#inherit pkgconfig lib_package setuptools distutils     #py2 - working solution
inherit pkgconfig lib_package setuptools3               #py3??????

SRC_URI = "file://setup.py \
           file://dialog.py \
           file://main.py \
           file://__init__.pyc \
           file://plugin.pyc \
           file://Esttv.png \
"

S = "${WORKDIR}"

do_compile () {
     python setup.py build_ext --inplace
}

do_install () {
    install -d ${D}${libdir}/zurka/python/Plugins/Extensions/EstTV

    install    ${WORKDIR}/*.pyc  ${D}${libdir}/zurka/python/Plugins/Extensions/EstTV/

    install -m 0755 ${S}/dialog.so ${D}${libdir}/zurka/python/Plugins/Extensions/EstTV/
    install -m 0755 ${S}/main.so ${D}${libdir}/zurka/python/Plugins/Extensions/EstTV/

}
```

Cythonize script (setup.py):

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

def cythonize_modules():
    return cythonize([
        "dialog.py",
        "main.py",
    ],
        language_level=3,  # python3
    )

setup(ext_modules=cythonize_modules())
```

Error:

```
ERROR: zurka-plugin-extensions-EstTV-py3-4.0-r0 do_fetch: Fetcher failure: 
Unable to find file file://__init__.pyc anywhere. 
The paths that were searched were:
    /mnt/h4/7.0/meta-mi/recipes-plugins/zurka-plugin-extensions-EstTV-py3-4.0/mi
    /mnt/h4/7.0/meta-mi/recipes-plugins/zurka-plugin-extensions-EstTV-py3/mi 
    /mnt/h4/7.0/meta-mi/recipes-plugins/files/mi
    /mnt/h4/7.0/meta-mi/recipes-plugins/zurka-plugin-extensions-EstTV-py3/
    etc...
```

As you can see `__init__.pyc` is inside folder `zurka-plugin-extensions-EstTV-py3`.

What about inherit, when i put setuptools (without 3) error is different; Could not inherit file classes/setuptools.bbclass.

When i put setuptools3 error is; missing file (`__init__.pyc`).

When i put distutils, error is different again (i can't remember which one exactly).

So, what i can do next?
Thank you!

---

EDIT:

after i change do compile line from `python setup.py build_ext --inplace` to `python3 ${S}/setup.py build_ext --inplace` now i have another type of error.

```
Log data follows:
| DEBUG: Executing shell function do_compile
| Traceback (most recent call last):
|   File "/mnt/h4/7.0/builds/ja2/release/sf3000/tmp/work/cortexa15hf-neon-vfpv4-oe-linux-gnueabi/zurka-plugin-extensions-EstTV-py3/5.0-r0/setup.py", line 5, in <module>
|     ext_modules = cythonize("dialog.py")
|   File "/mnt/h4/7.0/builds/ja2/release/sf3000/tmp/work/cortexa15hf-neon-vfpv4-oe-linux-gnueabi/zurka-plugin-extensions-EstTV-py3/5.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 965, in cythonize
|     module_list, module_metadata = create_extension_list(
|   File "/mnt/h4/7.0/builds/ja2/release/sf3000/tmp/work/cortexa15hf-neon-vfpv4-oe-linux-gnueabi/zurka-plugin-extensions-EstTV-py3/5.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 815, in create_extension_list
|     for file in nonempty(sorted(extended_iglob(filepattern)), "'%s' doesn't match any files" % filepattern):
|   File "/mnt/h4/7.0/builds/ja2/release/sf3000/tmp/work/cortexa15hf-neon-vfpv4-oe-linux-gnueabi/zurka-plugin-extensions-EstTV-py3/5.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 114, in nonempty
|     raise ValueError(error_msg)
| ValueError: 'dialog.py' doesn't match any files
```

Comment: Are the `.pyc` files actually part of the source code? Typically they're generated during the `setup.py build...` step and therefore should not be in `SRC_URI`

Comment: yes, they are precompiled and they are parts of the project.

Comment: They are not a part of cythonize function (only dialog.py and main.py). pyc files are already compiled before and part of the project as they are.

Comment: Could you try inheriting setuptools3_legacy instead of setuptools3 ?

Comment: @Florain Berndl - setuptools3_legacy:
Could not inherit file classes/setuptools3_legacy.bbclass.


Unrelated to setuptools3_legacy... 
I change do compile line from python to python 3 and now i have another error.
But pls check again the post. I just edited.